How to remove nvidia packages before already having ubuntu installed?
I've had a lot of trouble trying to dual boot windows 11 and ubuntu 24.04. Currently when I choose to boot from my USB drive with the 24.04.iso, for the first time, I get a pitch black screen when pressing "Try or install Ubuntu" and I get a constant loading Ubuntu logo when writing nomodeset. I haven't even reached the new installer yet
I might've narrowed the problem down to having to remove nvidia packages according to this person.
The issue is that I have no idea how to remove nvidia packages if I don't already have Ubuntu 24.04 installed? I wanna use 24.04 since the default 6.8 kernel is needed for my HP Spectre x360 2024's Intel Arc I believe. I've never run any kind of Ubuntu and this is my first attempt dual booting.
If you can help please dumb it down as much as possible, I've never done anything in Linux really other than a few already-set-up virtual machines
PS. If you know that this isn't the solution to finally dualbooting for me you can see what else I've tried here

"if I don't already have Ubuntu 24.04 installed?"  + " I'm dual booting windows 11 and ubuntu 24.04"  what is it? and what do you mean? The installer has an option to not install 3rd party driver so what is the problem you believe to have?!

Yeah okay I see your point, I've edited the question. To summarize I get a black screen now and want to remove nvidia packages. I don't already have ubuntu and haven't dual booted before

Did you hashcheck the downloaded ISO?  Is your machine's firmware up-to-date?  All sorts of problems may be caused by those two items.

The ISO is freshly downloaded. And the firmware is up-to-date. I just need to know how to remove nvidia packages without already having ubuntu, as the question asks

you'll probably need to create a new ISO for Ubuntu, the package packer may come useful @Jamari
